# Blocking REST API calls

Tags: security, authentication, rest

is there a way to block REST API calls to a non authorized client?
is there a way to make the API "limited" to (public for) only small number of well defined clients?

thanks :-)

Comment: You need to secure who can connect to the server.

Comment: REST doesn't expose APIs. You're confused with RPC. `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST`

Comment: Assuming you mean something other than REST, what server platform/language/framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy mutually-authenticated SSL between your clients and your server. You can use self-signed certificates here so you don't need to buy any from a CA. This will ensure that your server only accepts requests from clients that have the client-side certificate (configure your server to only accept the self-signed client certificates deployed on your clients for client authentication).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RESTFul HTTP

you can add an HttpServletFilter to your web.xml which prevents unauthorized clients from accessing your REST Methods.

See
[Securing JAX-RS and RESTeasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html)

If you use the Spring Framework you and you don't want to implement your own HttServletFilter you can use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement security mechanisms in your RESTful Service, so it denies access to unauthorized clients (with a 404 or 401 response code). There are several ways to achieve this:

- Relay on HTTP authentication mechanisms, like [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- Implement a Custom Authentication framework, that overcomes HTTP Basic Authentication limitations. [Amazon](http://onjava.com/onjava/2007/11/07/introduction-to-amazon-s3-with-java-and-rest.html) has an interesting approach that includes custom HTTP headers and supports hashing.
- Use an existing security framework and add its capabilities to your service. [Spring Security](http://java.dzone.com/articles/securing-restful-web-service) sounds like a great option.